# Application Kills When Fiddler / Wireshark starts

Tags: windows, security, wireshark, fiddler

So I have that `.exe` here and whenever it detects `wireshark / fiddler` it kills itself, how can I prevent that?

How do I hide `fiddler` or `wireshark`?

I know this program even scans these words when browsing via web cause it just killed itself when I wrote word "`wireshark`".

Comment: You should take a loot at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. Can you provide more details (what is this application called)? If it can kill itself when you type "wireshark", it's probably listening to your keyboard, but if it kills itself when you go to a wireshark website, then it's listening to processes (tab title can register as part of a chrome process name).

Comment: The easiest way would be to run Wireshark and/or Fiddler on a separate computer in the same network and redirect the traffic through that PC.

Comment: First investigate how the program is detecting that the tools are running:
by detecting type strokes (ouch, it's like a virus); by scanning the active processes; by detecting changes in the system proxy settings. If you provide this information, you'll probably get your answer.